# changing Named range reference after inserting columns

Tags: excel, vba, reference, named-ranges

I have a Code that adds columns to the end of named ranges. For that purpose, I defined "LastM" and "LastQ", which Count the columns in the named range and then I am copying the columns (see Code below).

However, once the columns are inserted, the named range expands but the value of "LastM" is fixed and I can no longer use it for further operations.

Is there any way to make "LastM" variable i.e the columns are being counted again after adding columns to the named range?

I think I could just define a new "LastM2" and Count the columns again but I feel this is not a very effcient solution.

Thanks for the help!

```
'Adding 3 rows to monthly Data
LastM = ws.Range("Monthly").Columns.Count
Set Rng1 = Range("Monthly").Columns(LastM).Offset(0, -1)
Set Rng2 = Range("Monthly").Columns(LastM).Offset(0, -3)
Range(Rng1, Rng2).Copy
Range(Rng1, Rng2).EntireColumn.Offset(0, 3).Insert

'Adding 1 row to Quaterly Data
LastQ = ws.Range("Quaterly").Columns.Count
Set Rng3 = Range("Quaterly").Columns(LastQ).Offset(0, -1)
Rng3.Copy
Rng3.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert

'LAstQ and LastM are fixed but the Named range expanded'
```

Comment: I you don't need to keep the old count just overwrite what you had in LastM.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
with ws.Range("Monthly")
    'Adding 3 rows to monthly Data
    Set Rng1 = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Offset(0, -1)
    Set Rng2 = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Offset(0, -3)
    Range(Rng1, Rng2).Copy
    Range(Rng1, Rng2).EntireColumn.Offset(0, 3).Insert
end with

with ws.Range("Quaterly")
    'Adding 1 row to Quaterly Data
    Set Rng3 = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Offset(0, -1)
    Rng3.Copy
    Rng3.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
end with
```